# Automapper nested mappings and grouping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, automapper

I'd like to get list of tasks grouped by TaskHead with list of tasks inside.

TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO.TaskHead == TaskItemToReturnDTO.ItemStage

Entity

```
    public class TaskItem
    {
        [Key]
        public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ItemStage { get; set; }
    }
```

DTOs

```
    public class TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO
    {
        public string TaskHead { get; set; }
        public ICollection<TaskItemToReturnDTO> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public class TaskItemToReturnDTO
    {
        public int TaskItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ItemStage { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpGet("all")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<TaskItem>>> GetTasks()
        {
            var tasks = await _context.TaskItems.ToListAsync();
            var mappedTasks = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO>>(tasks);

            return Ok(mappedTasks);
        }
```

AutoMapper Profile

```
            CreateMap<TaskItem, TaskItemToReturnDTO>().ReverseMap();

            CreateMap<TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO, TaskItem>().ReverseMap()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.TaskHead, c => c.MapFrom(c => c.ItemStage))
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Tasks, c => c.MapFrom(c => new List<TaskItemToReturnDTO> { new TaskItemToReturnDTO
                {
                    TaskItemId = c.TaskItemId,
                    Name = c.Name,
                    ItemStage = c.ItemStage
                }}));
```

This is my current result, but the tasks are not grouped.

```
[
    {
        "taskHead": "Design done",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 1,
                "name": "Issuing",
                "itemStage": "Design done"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Design done",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 2,
                "name": "Issuing",
                "itemStage": "Design done"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Design being checked",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 4,
                "name": "SF Joists",
                "itemStage": "Design being checked"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Design being checked",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 5,
                "name": "FF Joists",
                "itemStage": "Design being checked"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Being issued",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 6,
                "name": "Roof",
                "itemStage": "Being issued"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Below I have shown how it should look like. This is my goal.

```
[
    {
        "taskHead": "Design done",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 1,
                "name": "Issuing",
                "itemStage": "Design done"
            },
          {
                "taskItemId": 2,
                "name": "Issuing",
                "itemStage": "Design done"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Design being checked",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 4,
                "name": "SF Joists",
                "itemStage": "Design being checked"
            },
          {
                "taskItemId": 5,
                "name": "FF Joists",
                "itemStage": "Design being checked"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "taskHead": "Being issued",
        "tasks": [
            {
                "taskItemId": 6,
                "name": "Roof",
                "itemStage": "Being issued"

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I think I should use GroupBy function somewhere but I cant figure out where and how. Maybe I have wrong mapping?

Comment: Why do you need AM for one-time request? AM not for generating queries but for mapping one object to another.

Answer (score 1):

Automapper works fine for `TaskItemToReturnDTO`, but you don't need to crate a mapper for `TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO`. Instead, use linq for grouping after mapping as follows:

```
var mappedTasks = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TaskItemToReturnDTO>>(tasks);
var groupedTasks = mappedTasks
    .GroupBy(task => task.ItemStage)
    .Select(group => new TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO { TaskHead = group.Key, Tasks = group.ToList() });
```

Answer (score 0):

@Oignon_Rouge
Thank you, already figured out with pretty similar code... can you check if my version is okay? Works fine for me :)

```
        [HttpGet("all")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<ICollection<TaskItem>>> GetTasks()
        {
            var tasks = await _context.TaskItems.ToListAsync();
            var mappedTasks = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO>>(tasks);

            var groupedTasks = mappedTasks.GroupBy(z => z.TaskHead).Select(v => new TaskItemToReturnHeadDTO
            {
                TaskHead = v.Key,
                Tasks = _mapper.Map<ICollection<TaskItemToReturnDTO>>(tasks).Where(x => x.ItemStage == v.Key).ToList()
            });

            return Ok(groupedTasks);
        }
```

Comment: the answer of Oignon_Rouge is better in terms of performance and cleaner code. You are mapping twice time the tasks. You better to group directly tasks and only map the grouping list as Oignon_Rouge suggests.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).